# Interesting problem about function pointer casting

Tags: c++, type-conversion, function-pointers

I have made a interesting test about function pointer cast:

```cpp
typedef bool (*BFUNC)(int n);
typedef int  (*IFUNC)(int n);
typedef double (*DFUNC)(int n);

void vfunc(int n)
{
    n++;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BFUNC f = (BFUNC)vfunc;
    IFUNC f2 = (IFUNC)vfunc;
    DFUNC f3 = (DFUNC)vfunc;

    bool bRet = f(0);
    int nRet = f2(0);
    double dRet = f3(0);

    printf("bRet=%d, nRet=%d\n", bRet, nRet); // bRet=1, nRet=1

    return 0;
}
```

The first interesting thing is that this code compiles and runs fine. The second interesting thing is that I actually get the return value, which seems to be 1 at the moment. (I'm using very old VS2010, don't know if it has anything to do with it)

I want to know what happened?

I did some more experimenting, and it seems that as long as I use this C-style explicit conversion, then I'm pretty free to cast one function pointer type to another, I'm wondering if there's a practical point to this? What is its underlying principle?

Comment: You are invoking *undefined behavior* by casting the function pointer to an incompatible type. You are getting a "correct" return value by coincidence

Comment: _"What is its underlying principle?"_ regarding c++ _undefined behavior_ I'd say.

Comment: "I actually get the return value" No, you don't. There is no return value in `vFunc`. Whatever you see (btw: you do not print anything) is some indetermined value. Using them causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I'm going to have a look at "Undefined Behavior"

Comment: Do you use C or C++? Only tag one.

Comment: Sorry, I use c++ and delete the c tag

Comment: Read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) - including all the very good articles linked at the end.

Comment: *"The first interesting thing is that this code compiles and runs fine."* -- Why is this interesting? You started by dumping a bunch of code that I have no motivation to read. What are you trying to demonstrate? Introducing the problem *before* posting any code (cf. [ask]) has the benefits of getting people interested and of making it possible for the next person with the same question to find yours.

Comment: "The first interesting thing is that this code compiles and runs fine." - That is actually not that interesting. That code compiles is a *very* low bar to pass when talking about correctness of the program. Lots of broken code compiles.

Comment: The first three lines of `_tmain()` use C-style casts, so forces the conversion of function pointers.   Remove those casts, and the code will not compile.   Since you have forced the conversion, the subsequent usage of those function pointers (to call the function) gives undefined behaviour.   One of the "joys" of undefined behaviour is that the observed behaviour can seem to make sense (that is one perfectly acceptable outcome).

Comment: I apologize if the way I ask this offends you, this is my first time asking. But I think it may not need too many reasons to be interesting, just like @Mestkon 's answer, there may be some definite behavior behind this undefined behavior, I also tried to verify it, I think this is quite interesting : )

Comment: @UnholySheep — the cast is okay; calling through the resulting pointer means that the behavior of the program is undefined. The pointer can be “used”, however, by casting it back to its original type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the reason why C-style casts have been superseded by C++ style casts (`static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, ...).

C-style casts will attempt to do any of the C++ style casts in a [predetermined order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). In your case, the C-style cast is equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`. Therefore the casts work fine.

By invoking the function after `reinterpret_cast`ing it to a pointer to an incompatible function signature, you are invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Any discussion about the return value is moot as this is purely undefined behavior and therefore could potentially result in anything happening.

(But if you absolutely want to know why the return value is `1`, then it might be because the `n++` operation will store its result on the stack where the return value is expected to be stored. After all, this functions does not have a return value, so why should it reserve stack space for one?).

Comment: Wow, I added an `n++` and it really turned into 2! Thanks!

Comment: To see the undefined behavior in action you can take a look at [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xz3PGP4W4) live compiler comparison. Different compilers and even the same compiler with different optimization levels produce completly different output.

Answer (score 1):

Every function has an address in memory and callable in a different ways.

```
typedef bool (*BFUNC)(int n);
typedef int  (*IFUNC)(int n);
typedef double (*DFUNC)(int n);
```

When you don't use it, the return type doesn't matter at all.
In x86 assembly, regardless of the return type you define, the variations of the AX register are used for returning values.

In this case, no matter how you define your function, as long as you utilize the returned value, nothing will change.
If you attempt to use it, the value you receive will be irrelevant.

When function types are compiled into assembly code, they determine what size of value will be returned, and unless you make a function's type 'void,' the assembly result will be written to the variations of the AX register.

Apart from readability and usage of the code, it doesn't change much else.

Comment: is this answer for C ? Afaik in c++ the return type does matter

Comment: *"regardless of the return type you define, the variations of the AX register are used for returning values"* - not really true, floating point numbers are generally stored in floating-point registers, not the general purpose registers

Comment: I missed that spot, thanks